# Moveit 2 On Windows 11: ROS2-Humble Hawksbill

Tags: ros2, moveit, installation, ros-humble, windows

Has anyone tried installing MoveIt 2 on windows? When I go to the [official website](https://moveit.ros.org/install-moveit2/binary-windows/) it says nothing about compatibility with ROS-humble version. It's very similar to how it doesn't mention anything for compatibility with ROS-Iron and it is still compatible in Linux. I tried this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows) but it has lack of information. Can anyone tell if there is any way to install MoveIt 2 on windows for ROS-Humble? I didn't find any resources online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at installing via [Robostack](https://robostack.github.io) and see if your needs can be met that way:

https://robostack.github.io/GettingStarted.html

https://robostack.github.io/humble.html

Some core MoveIt packages are available for binary installation. I successfully installed `ros-humble-moveit` on an existing Robostack Humble installation. I can add a motion planning panel to RViz.

However, `moveit2_tutorials` is not available to try a more functional test per the [quickstart documentation](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/tutorials/quickstart_in_rviz/quickstart_in_rviz_tutorial.html). I briefly looked into building it from source, but it looks like I'll have to try to build a number of its dependencies from source too.

EDIT: I added a number of packages from source and got the `moveit2_tutorials` RViz quickstart working:

[image]

`moveit2_tutorials` depends on a number of packages that as far as I know aren't available on Windows and might be hard to build.

I currently removed the dependencies `moveit_task_constructor_core`, `moveit_ros_perception` and `moveit_servo` from [the `CMakeLists.txt` in `moveit2_tutorials`](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2_tutorials/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt) and commented out all the `add_subdirectory()` calls except for `add_subdirectory(doc/tutorials/quickstart_in_rviz)`

I will fork it and make a Windows branch to share later, and update with another edit, as well as share a `.repos` file. I needed to build `graph_msgs`, `moveit_resources`, `moveit_visual_tools` and `rviz_visual_tools` from source.

--- End Edit ---

You might give it a try and see if you can get a working installation. You can also check out https://github.com/ms-iot/ROSOnWindows/issues and see if there's any information about MoveIt.

Are you planning to control real robot hardware? Even if you get MoveIt working with demos/simulation, hardware driver support tends to be limited.

Comment: Yes I was trying to to control real robot hardware and as linux system was not available I wanted to build this on windows.

Comment: I think it's worth trying Robostack. I'm having issues building `moveit2_tutorials` with a fresh Robostack installation because the tutorial code now seems to rely on `ros2_kortex`, the Kinova driver package. The screenshot above with the Franka Emika Panda is using an old Robostack installation I haven't maintained in a while. However, basic MoveIt is available and if you can get your robot driver to work on Windows, I bet you can get MoveIt to work with it at some level.